# How do I plot this simple thing correctly in Octave?

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I am a student trying to learn how to use Octave and I need help with plotting this thing right here [the function I want to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqpXH.png)

The code looks like this:

```
x2 = 0:0.1:50;
y2 = power((1+(2.*x2/(exp(0.5.*x2)+(x2.^2)))), 0.5);
plot(x2, y2, '-b');
```

It feels like it should have plotted without problems but the plot in the figure appears to be completely empty, and I cannot wrap my head around why this might happen. Would love to know what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the value of `y2` (simply type `y2` and press enter) then you find that `y2` is a single number rather than a vector.

To find out out why `y2` is a single number we type in the calculation `power((1+(2.*x2/(exp(0.5.*x2)+(x2.^2)))), 0.5)` and remove the outer functions/operators step by step. Once the result is a vector we know that the last thing removed ruined the result.

In your case `/` turns out to be the culprit.
From [Octave, Arithmetic Ops](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Arithmetic-Ops.html) (emphasis mine):

> `x / y`
> Right division. This is conceptually equivalent to the expression `(inv (y') * x')'` but it is computed without forming the inverse of `y'`.
> **If the system is not square**, or if the coefficient matrix is singular, **a minimum norm solution is computed**.

> `x ./ y`
> Element-by-element right division.

Therefore, replace `/` by `./`.

```
x2 = 0:0.1:50;
y2 = power(1 + 2 .* x2 ./ (exp(0.5 .* x2) + (x2 .^ 2)), 0.5);
plot(x2, y2, '-b');
```

[image: plot]